# Weird Behavior with Jquery image slideshow... Help!

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow

I built a jquery slideshow based on the tutorial found here:
http://www.queness.com/post/152/simple-jquery-image-slide-show-with-semi-transparent-caption

It seems to be working perfectly fine, except that it behaves strangley right at the beginning when it displays the first image. The first image appears like normal and then flashes, fades to white and disappears completely. After that, the first slide reappears and behaves normally, transitioning to the next image.

The slideshow in question is center page on the right:
http://www.loftist.com/

I am not a JS developer, so I am not sure how to troubleshoot this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's the problem, but it's always a good first step to ensure you mark-up validates first - http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.loftist.com%2F

Comment: Yeah, I had it validated earlier and still had these problems - its not validating right now because I am working on a separate plugin. Validated or not, the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. For future reference, if anyone comes up against this problem with this particular script, the first image needs, to have the class "show" applied to it and all subsequent images need to have some different class.